# WCF service doesn't work in multiple server environment

Tags: c#, wcf, amazon-ec2, windows-services, load-balancing

I have the next architecture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLvR0.png

Load Balancers are customized on AWS. WCF is hosted by a Windows Service.
It works when only one API send a request or two APIs sent a request and Load Balancer redirect both to WCF1 (or WCF2) server.

When API1 and API2 send request at the same time WCF1 returns response with error:

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply;  this might be caused
>   by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown  or an internal
>   server error.

and WCF2 returns a response with error:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing  your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:59:59.7299730'.

Endpoint configuration:

```
var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding
{                
    ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1f),
    MaxBufferSize = 52428800,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 52428800,
    SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
    Security = new NetTcpSecurity()
    {
        Mode = SecurityMode.None,
        Message = new MessageSecurityOverTcp()
        {
            ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None
        },
            Transport = new TcpTransportSecurity()
            {
                ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None,
                ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None,
            }
        }
 };
```

Endpoint address:

```
net.tcp://LoadBalancerHost:port/ServiceName;
```

WCF configuration:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
```

I'm not familiar with Load Balancing and it seems that something is missing in configuration.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS loadbalancer only allows HTTP connections.